# Keep image at bottom of div, but text slightly above

Tags: html, css, css-position, margin, absolute

http://jsfiddle.net/Hz4JF/1/ shows my html + css.

My goal is to have the image ride the bottom of the container, and the text have a small margin that does not cause the image to be nudged up.

It's Monday, so excuse me if this is a no-brainer.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="superimpose">
        <img id="photo" src="http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/10391672/2/stock-photo-10391672-portrait-of-a-businessman-with-arms-crossed.jpg">
        <div id="text">
            <span id="name">Bob Smith</span>
            <span id="phone">123-456-7891</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#superimpose{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
#photo, #text{
    display: inline-block;
}
#text{
    margin-bottom:15px;
    text-align: center;
}
#text span{
    display: block;
}
```

P.S. - I'm using spans in #text for good reason.

Comment: Are you trying to have the text display 15px above the image at all times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `vertical-align: bottom;` to `#photo, #text` produces a result similar to your description:

http://jsfiddle.net/zeTjn/3/

Is this what you seek?

Comment: Perfect - thanks! This matched exactly to my request.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to [margin collapse](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins). Just add `overflow: auto;`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/Hz4JF/6/

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution (I'm not sure if i understand exactly your Problem):
http://jsfiddle.net/Hz4JF/11/

```
#text{
    position:relative;
    bottom:100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```